# Open source projects using BDD testing?

Tags: c#, java, vb.net, bdd

My team is interesting in understanding BDD better.

Are there open source .NET/Java projects which use behavior driven development (BDD)?

I would like to focus my attention on static language examples.

Comment: Should be on [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Cellz](http://cellz.codeplex.com/) which is a functional Excel-like spreadsheet application for Silverlight has some BDD tests written using [TickSpec](http://tickspec.codeplex.com/). Both projects are using F# to some point, but you can probably learn something from them even if you're not an F# developer (TickSpec can be used from C# too).

[Phil Trelford](http://www.trelford.com/blog) who is the author of both of these projects also did a talk about BDD and TickSpec at F#unctional Londoners user group. You can [watch the recording here](http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/scala/tickspec-bdd-for-c-sharp-f-sharp).

Answer (score 0):

I got these for java:

- [jbehave](http://jbehave.org)
- [jdave](http://jdave.org)
- [tumbler-glass](http://code.google.com/p/tumbler-glass/)
- [easyb](http://easyb.org)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you search GitHub?

[c# code with features(specflow/cucumber) in it](https://github.com/search?type=Code&language=csharp&q=features&repo=&langOverride=&x=20&y=20&start_value=1)

[c# code that uses MSpec](https://github.com/search?type=Code&language=csharp&q=Machine.Specifications&repo=&langOverride=&x=0&y=0&start_value=1)

[Fluent NHibernate](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate) is a fairly big project that user MSpec

[Machine.Specifications](https://github.com/machine/machine.specifications) uses itself too

Answer (score 0):

I offer the little project I've been working on: [WipFlash](http://code.google.com/p/wipflash). It's a C# automation tool for WPF, with a little mock up of a pet shop and scenarios around the pet shop. The scenarios are a bit lower level than I'd recommend (focus on capabilities, not details) - but you should get the idea of how to start, at least.

The unit-level code is also worked using BDD, focusing on examples of behavior rather than testing methods.

Both scenarios and class-level examples are written using plain old NUnit. BDD really isn't about the tools.

As Zsolt suggested, we did develop JBehave using BDD but I think the scenarios are less comprehensive there and it's hard to set up without delving into Maven-land (sorry!)

Answer (score 0):

The Should assertion library is using MSpec: http://should.codeplex.com/ (at least, the fluent should interface is test with mspec.  I haven't looked at it all)

Orchard CMS is using SpecFlow http://www.orchardproject.net/

Answer (score 0):

The Play framework uses BDD for testing, but that's in Scala

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play-json/src/test/scala/play/api/libs/json/JsonTransSpec.scala

Answer (score 0):

[Spring Content](https://github.com/paulcwarren/spring-content) is using [Ginkgo4j](http://paulcwarren.github.io/ginkgo4j/) - a Java port of Ruby's RSpec BDD Framework.